# How to embed Firebird with winbinder?

Tags: php, firebird

Is there anyway that I can use firebird with my winbinder standalone application?
i'm developing simple windows application with winbinder and I was trying to embed firebird with my application. does anybody knows how to do this if its possible?

Comment: Why not use SQLite? That's much more phpish than firebird.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it with Winbinder specifically, but the embedded Firebird server is great for this.

It is basically a Firebird client library with the database server included in it.  When you use a local connection (i.e. one without localhost: or server: in front) it will access it using the embedded server instead.